# TCPDF justify text with dynamic underline/border bottom

Tags: php, html, css, tcpdf

I am having trouble to implement this design to TCPDF, the output is screenshot on the attached image. [image] (Considering TCPDF has limited html markup)

There would be a dynamic underline depending on the value of fields,
Some fields with no text will have default underline that will correspond to the layout

Should you able to provide a sample html, can you please add it to plunkr or other online tools, would highly be appreciated.

TY

Comment: - when considering table, the width of col1 would become fix leading to spacing on columns with smaller texts so Table would seem to be inappropriate, unless otherwise...

Comment: - also considered mathematically add  dynamic <u>&nbsp;</ul>, but the calculation from my formula is intermittently does not fix to the 100% width... (if you like to see this code pls let me know )

Answer (score 0):

You can use div inside your TD.

```
<td style="color:#000; font-size:9px;"><div class="underlined">Some Text</div></td>
```

with css

```
.underlined { 
      border-bottom: 0.1em solid #000;       
}
```

This will print underline under text even when text is not available.

Answer (score -1):

How about using HTML2PDF?

HTML2PDF handles HTML better than TCPDF: it allows you to use CSS classes and it has more cool functions, specially for dynamic content which TCPDF doesn't do well.

Download [HTML2PDF](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default) or go to their website and look at the examples.

http://html2pdf.fr/en/default

Comment: Hi @Meabed, thanks for this information I am now checking html2pdf if it can address this formatting. Thanks